# Running simple `Renjin` example on net-beans, with Java code : "Using R within a Java project"

Tags: java, r, jri, renjin

I'm trying to run this example from the `Renjin` website, http://www.renjin.org/documentation/developer-guide.html, I'm trying to run the first "A simple primer" example.

following is my directory layout:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import org.renjin.sexp.*; // <-- import Renjin's object classes
/**
 *
 * @author yschellekens
 */
public class StackOverflow {  

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    // create a Renjin engine
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("Renjin");
    // evaluate R code from String, cast SEXP to a DoubleVector and store in the 'res' variable
    DoubleVector res = (DoubleVector)engine.eval("a <- 2; b <- 3; a*b");
    System.out.println("The result of a*b is: " + res);     

    }
}
```

Why am i getting the following Exception? (i should get of 6)

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stackoverflow.StackOverflow.main(StackOverflow.java:22)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is throw because your application can't find the Renjin ScriptEngine. You have provided renjin-studio as a library, but you need the renjin-script-engine library which is available from [http://build.bedatadriven.com/job/renjin/lastSuccessfulBuild/org.renjin$renjin-script-engine/](http://build.bedatadriven.com/job/renjin/lastSuccessfulBuild/org.renjin%24renjin-script-engine/) (use the JAR with dependencies).

Unfortunately `ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName()` only returns `null` if it can't find the engine so you can add the following check to ensure that the engine has loaded:

```
// check if the engine has loaded correctly:
if(engine == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Renjin Script Engine not found on the classpath.");
}
```

Also note: it is called *Renjin*, not *Rengin*!

Comment: Sorry for the Rengin mistake, ill check the code on monday and let you know. btw, this project is really cool, the `JRI` alternative is terrible.

Comment: and there it works:    run:
The result of a*b is: 6.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: I must say i noticed that both you and your partner, arn't much into stack overflow, notice that all of the r guru's use this site to promote their packages, i think it would be good for your product as well.

Comment: Glad it now works and that you're excited about the project! Regarding our presence on SO: there are not that many questions being asked here that concern Renjin. We have a [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/renjin-dev) that is quite active. It's also easier to keep track of questions there as we get an e-mail notification whenever someone posts a message.

Comment: i guess ill just take care of the questions :)

Comment: ill ask some colleagues with high reputation to create the tag `Renjin`